# Can I store objects created in a DLL after unloading the DLL?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, dll

I need some clarification on the following code.

In the following code, I am retrieving a private implementation of an interface from a DLL.

After the DLL has been unloaded(CASE #2), the string retrieved from the interface, and the interface itself both become invalid, and access violations occur(expected) when they are accessed.

But what's confusing me, is that when when I reload the DLL, I can use the interface and the string again, without re-retrieving them from the DLL.

Is this supposed to work this way?

How can the memory become invalid, and them suddenly become valid again once the DLL is loaded again?

Is this just luck, and the DLL conveniently loading into the exact same place in memory the second time because of the relative simplicity of my test program?

```
int main(int argc, int *argv[])
{
    Interface *itf;
    const char *name;

    {
        // loads the dll and gets functions
        PersistenInterface pi("PersistentInterface.dll");

        // returns a private implementation of the interface
        itf = pi.CreateInterface();
        name = itf->GetName();

        // CASE #1
        cout << name << endl; // suceeds

    } // dll is unloaded in ~PersistenInterface()

    // CASE #2
    //cout << name << endl; // crashes
    //cout << itf->GetName() << endl; // crashes

    {
        PersistenInterface pi("PersistentInterface.dll");

        // CASE #3
        cout << name << endl; // suceeds !?
        cout << itf->GetName() << endl; // suceeds !?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to know how `itf` and `name` are allocated in `pi`?

Comment: "name" was allocated on the stack. I switched to returning strdup(name), and case #2 no longer crashes for the string. The interface still crashes, but that makes sense because the code is no longer loaded(the pvt imp is in the dll). It also then makes sense that the interface would work again after reloading the dll. What is still throwing me off, is that I have had a .lib with a singleton in it before, which I linked to the both the DLL and the main program, and then ended up with two unique copies of the Singleton(one in the app and one in the dll. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: The ".lib" you mentioned is the import library of a DLL or another statically-linked DLL library?

Comment: no, just a static utility library containing things I need in both the main program and also the DLL

Comment: The singleton pointers were being allocated using the lazy init method Sinleton& GetSingleton() { static Singleton s; return s; }. I can understand this crashing when the dll unloads per the previous situation, but why the two copies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are not returning a local object on stack from DLL. It will definitely crash your system because the local object is destroyed after function returns from the DLL. It has nothing to do with the concept of DLL. If you try to reference a local object after its containing function returns, you'll see the same problem.

If the memory is dynamically allocated on heap inside DLL, it's still valid after the DLL is uninitialized. You can still use the memory in your main application, because DLL itself doesn't own anything. Remember, the heap belongs to the process, not DLL.

However, the general rule is that the owner of that memory(who creates that memory, e.g. the DLL in your case) is responsible to release the same memory. Allocating memory in DLL and deallocating it in the other side may cause you unnecessary troubles, if the two sides use different instances of CRT, e.g.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a little complex. Actually, if you load a DLL, it is not really loaded in your heap memory. It is loaded in global memory and this memory is mapped into your address-space.With this mechanism the OS saves memory, because it can map the same code into different processes. So if you access an address within the DLL space, the access will be redirect into the global memory where the DLL really exist. After unloading, there is no memory anymore at this address. Your access will not be redirect any more, a exception will be thrown. This is different to a malloc and free (or new and delete) where only the memory is marked as unused, but still there with all its data (unless zero out memory is activated). Static DLL data (like constant strings) and code of a DLL acts like described above. After you load a DLL again, the addresses you have, which obviously direct to static data or code, became valid again. At least Windows XP loads a DLL always at the same address-space. But do not rely on this! For security reason, modern OS can decide to map DLLs of your process on different addresses on every time loadLibrary is used or every time you start your process. In the debugger or with Windows XP, DLL's are always mapped at the same address as far as I know, that's the reason of the behavior for your code. It is not a bug or a feature, it is by DLL concept.